# jquery-html accordion menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I have a problem with the submenu. Because it's located in the `<li>` the submenu toggles with the color of the primary menu. I located my problem but i don't know how to solve it. It's because of the padding.

here is my css:

```
#menu li{
   margin-top: 1px;  
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   background-color: #1a1a1a;
   text-decoration: none;    
}
#menu li ul li{
   border: 0;
   margin: 0;
   display: none;
   background-color: #232323;
   text-indent: 15px;
   height: auto;
}
```

here is my jquery:

```
     $('#menu').find('li').click(function(){
         $(this).find('ul>li').fadeToggle('fast');
     });
```

and html:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li class="first current"><a id='home'>Home</a></li>
   <li class="has_current"><a id='#'>About</a>
<ul>
    <li class="first current"><a id='home'>Sub1</a></li>
    <li class="last current"><a id='home'>Sub2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I found the solution. I replace the `padding-bottom` and `padding-top` with `line-height` and it worked

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/cNM8r/.

Comment: yes, but i need the text to be in the middle of the `<li>`

Comment: For which `<ul>` (man nav or sub nav) do you want the text centered?

Comment: the text should be centered for both primary and sub

Comment: @user3360739: is this what you wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/cNM8r/9/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I created a sample here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fsz26/), but could not reproduce the issue.

Btw, the color you used for inner list is too dark, so I've changed it to light one to be able see something:

```
#menu li ul li{
   border: 0;
   margin: 0;
   display: none;
   background-color: **#ccc**;
   text-indent: 15px;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that when you click to open the submenu, it opens inside the `<li>` parent and as a consequence few pixels of the parent color remains on the bottom (black padding on the bottom). i hope I've explained it better

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the parent `background-color` in the nested list (or sub-navigation), you need to set `padding-left: 0;`. To get rid of the bullets, you can use `list-style: none;`. Below is an example of how to do that:

```
#menu,
#menu > li > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

[Example JSFiddle for above](http://jsfiddle.net/cNM8r/)

Next, you mentioned (in comments above) you wanted to center your links in both parent and subnav lists. To do that, you can do the below. What this does is it takes all `<a>`'s with a preceding `<li>` inside the element with an ID of `#menu` and sets them to display as a block level element, as well as centered text.

```
#menu li > a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white; /* added so you can see the links better */
}
```

Building from the first example, [here is an updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNM8r/1/) with centered links.

Comment: I think I didn't explained it right. Here is a sample [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Fsz26/). My problem is with those pixels at the bottom of the nav, when you open the subnav. It's all about the padding of the parent `<li>`.

Comment: Remove the `padding-bottom: 10px;` from `#menu li`. I'd recommend you add the padding to the `<a>` elements, and remove the padding in the `<li>`'s.